# Show that in every triangle $\cot\gamma-\cot\gamma_1=\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{6S}$

Tags: geometry

Let a triangle $ABC$ be given with $\measuredangle ACB=\gamma$ and $\measuredangle AGB=\gamma_1$, where $G$ is the centroid. Show that for every triangle $ABC$ the following equality holds: $$\cot\gamma-\cot\gamma_1=\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{6S}$$
[image]
Using that $\cot\gamma=\dfrac{\cos\gamma}{\sin\gamma},\cos\gamma=\dfrac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab},\sin\gamma=\dfrac{c}{2R}=\dfrac{c}{2\frac{abc}{4S}}=\dfrac{2S}{ab},$ we get $$\cot\gamma=\dfrac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{4S}$$ Then in triangle $ABG$ we would have $$\cot\gamma_1=\dfrac{\frac23m_a^2+\frac23m_b^2-c^2}{\frac43S}=\dfrac{2m_a^2+2m_b^2-3c^2}{4S}=\dfrac{4m_a^2+4m_b^2-6c^2}{8S}\\=\dfrac{2b^2+2c^2-a^2+2a^2+2c^2-b^2-6c^2}{8S}=\dfrac{a^2+b^2-2c^2}{8S}$$
Note that $S_{ABG}=\dfrac13S_{ABC}=\dfrac13S$.

In the authors' solution they have reached $\cot\gamma_1=\dfrac{a^2+b^2-5c^2}{12S}$. Can anyone spot my mistake, as I obviously cannot?

Answer (score 3):

It should be this:
$$\cot\gamma_1 = \dfrac{\left(\dfrac{2}{3}m_a\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{2}{3}m_b\right)^2 - c^2}{4\cdot\dfrac 13 S} = \ldots$$